# difference in sending a command from a pc or a mobile phone using bluetooth

Tags: c#, android, ios, bluetooth, xamarin

I am developing a cross platform app in C# using Xamarin. In my app I am using bluetooth to communicate between the app and a third party device.

Until now when sending short byte commands from all platforms everything works like a charm.
However, when sending a longer byte command (35 bytes) from the mobile phone (iOS and Android) it is as if the device didn't get any of the command or got some of it and couldn't make sense out of it.

I am sending the command as follow:

```
OutPutStream.Write(MyData.ToArray(), 0, NumberOfytes);
```

When I use the exact same lines of code with the same bytes on the PC, however, everything is fine and I am getting back the response I wanted.

I also tried to catch exceptions as specified on the [Android developer site](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/OutputStream.html#write%28byte%5B%5D%29) in the following way:

```
try
{
    OutPutStream.Write(MyData.ToArray(), 0, NumberOfytes);
}
catch (Java.Lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
{
    throw;
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    throw;
}
```

When I put the above lines in, the IOException is always called (even with the commands that do work) with **e** being null. The strange thing is that the **bytes are actually sent** and received for all commands (except the long one)! I am sure that all other commands are received properly because the received responses are unique and match the commands I am sending.

If anyone could tell me what am I doing wrong (if anything)? Or if there is a difference in the way I should be sending bytes over bluetooth across iOS and Android?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case other people are experiencing the same problem I am having, here is how I "solved" it. 
I eventually decided to try with a new Bluetooth device and it worked.

I am still intrigued as to how it always worked on the PC, but can just assume that perhaps it sends the bytes over Bluetooth more slowly or has better error control/ ACKs algorithm?

Hope this helps in some way. 
Cheers